# Shell script not running from cron

Tags: bash, scripts, cron, screen, jupyter

Server Ubuntu 16.04 running in a Virtual Box.

I had a server which I needed to rebuild (had no backups). I copied all relevant scripts I needed to reuse and all work as expected except one which is called from root cron. This worked well and without issues before. The script starts jupyter notebook in a screen session and when executed manually does what it is supposed to do. The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
# cd /home/<username>/jupyternb
screen -S jupyter -dm jupyter notebook
```

The crontab line is as follows:

```
@reboot sh /home/<username>/.STARTUP_SCRIPTS/start_jupyter.sh
```

(<username> is an actual user)

The shell script permissions are 777.

syslog shows the script is being called as root and reports no issues.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Basically to execute your script from anywhere, always use absolute path! System won't know where your script/executable lies, either it's path should be part of environment variable PATH or provide absolute path.

Comment: I updated both crontab and shell script to have absolute paths but still no success.

Comment: There are plenty of questions on here like this and I’ve never found a definitive guide about how to diagnose it. Sometimes it’s just paths, sometimes environment variables, and sometimes something else. You may well find it easier to use systemd units and timers. They are well documented and relatively easy to use. https://www.shellhacks.com/systemd-service-file-example/

Answer (score 0):

If syslog shows that job is being called then it could be a path issue.

Try to put the whole path `/usr/bin/screen` in script instead of just `screen` command.

```
#!/bin/bash
# cd /home/<username>/jupyternb
 /usr/bin/screen -S jupyter -dm jupyter notebook
```

Also you need to have end of line after each line in crontab, if that is the last line and there is no end of line character, job will not start.

Try checking with `mail` command for system mail of root user, or use `MAILTO=` in cron to get email which might have more details if something is failing when cron is run.

Comment: Thanks for input @rAlen I checked end of line on all lines in both shell script and crontab file. Also altered scripts to include full path to screen. All checks and updates did not result in progress.

Comment: @skywalker try checking system mail, or have cron send you email with MAILTO= sometimes mail will contain more details if something is failing to run

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by removing *cron* from the equation. https://forums.fast.ai/t/run-jupyter-notebook-on-system-boot/749/5 page was of great help.

The below is the jupyter.service file I had to create at /etc/systemd/system.

```
[Unit]
Description=Jupyter Workplace

[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/run/jupyter.pid
ExecStart=<path_to>/jupyter-notebook --config=<path_to>/jupyter_notebook_config.py
User=<username>
Group=<groupname>
WorkingDirectory=<start up path where notebooks are>
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then run the following:

```
systemctl enable jupyter.service
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart jupyter.service
```

Thank you everyone.