# FAIL seen on fast scrolling boot-up log

Tags: boot, 16.04, server

During bootup of Ubuntu Server some items show up with a red 'FAILED'. The scrolling is a bit fast to actually see what is being reported. Which log file would hold this information? Am assuming I will be able to read it with *nano*.

It is not /var/log/boot.log as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1303831/shell-script-not-running-from-cron/1303950#1303950).

Thank you

Comment: Can you pause/resume the scroll with `^S/^Q`? Or `grep FAIL /var/log/*log`. Note that Ubuntu 16.04 falls into Unsupported status this month. Time to start planning your upgrade.

Comment: Just a reminder 16.04 reaches end of standard support on April 22 2021. You may want to think about upgrading to 18.04 or 20.04. End of Stand Support means no more support or updates. You may not ask questions here either as 16.04 will be off topic. If you sign up for ESM you can still get security patches but that is all.

Comment: I am aware of End of Support for 16.04 however this machine has to stay at that version at this time. Thank you both for you responses.